# Is there a way to make this navigation transition smoother?

Tags: jquery

This is mostly completed (and correct as far as I know). When you scroll down, the logo and its round div change into a smaller logo, within the nav bar. View my Codepen and scroll down a bit to see what I mean: http://codepen.io/kaisle/pen/GJWLOZ

I just want it to be a smoother transition from the navigation bar when you scroll down, to the smaller version of the navigation bar. I assume it's something to do with fading-in the navigation once the nav becomes fixed. I've seen this done before, I just can't find out how to make it smoother!

Here's the problem area, I think:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var w = $(window).width();
if(w > 700) {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 120) {
        $('nav').css("position", "fixed");
      }
      else {
        $('nav').css("position", "relative");
      }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

});

Any help perfecting this at all would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://serialmentor.com/blog/2014/12/23/perfectly-smooth-transition-between-fixed-and-variable-positioning-of-html-elements-using-css-and-javascript, i just found it, if you're interested showing how to accomplish what you ask